# Significance of と in ~からといって

Tags: grammar, nuances

From what I've read, からいって means "considering this..."

> 人気や知名度**からいって**、彼が選挙で当選するのは確実だろう。

But when you add "と" to form "からといって" it becomes "even though..."

> すぐにメールの返事が来ない**からといって**、心配することはないと思う。

How does "と" change the meaning of the phrase? Or is it something that has no explanation and simply works this way?

Comment: In addition to l'électeur's answer, their structures are different. The former is [noun]+から, the latter is [clause(which has a predicate)]+から.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have **two totally different 「から's」** here.

> 「[人気]{にんき}や[知名度]{ちめいど}**から**いって、[彼]{かれ}が[選挙]{せんきょ}で[当選]{とうせん}するのは[確実]{かくじつ}だろう。」

This 「から」 means "from".  「～～からいう」 means "to judge from ~~".

> "Judging ***from*** his popularity and name value, it would be a sure thing for him to win the elections."

Onto the second sentence:

> 「すぐにメールの[返事]{へんじ}が[来]{こ}ない**からと**いって、[心配]{しんぱい}することはないと[思]{おも}う。」

This 「から」 means "because" and the 「と」 is a quotative particle.

「～～といって」 is very close to "(even) though" in meaning.

> "(Just) because a reply to your email has not come in, I do not think there is anything to be worried about."